# How I can save multiple contacts without using "saveContactTask"?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my application I want to keep several contacts on the phone book, but I want to do it transparently to the user. How I can do?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the SaveContactTask. Another public accessible way doesn't exist.
Maybe their is someday a homebrew way to do this but than is only suitable for a small percentage of users and the app wouldn't get certified for marketplace.